# subset pandas with different values but same index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataset from condition on values on another dataset

FROM

```
                 minV      maxV
2008-01-02        NaN       NaN
2008-01-03        NaN       NaN
2008-01-04  -0.022775       NaN
2008-01-07        NaN  0.010179
2008-01-08  -0.039777       NaN
2008-01-09        NaN       NaN
```

to

```
             val      
2008-01-04  1000     
2008-01-07  -1000 
2008-01-08  1000
```

i can get the list of index...but i am not sure what to do with it

```
    indexmin = df.index[df.minV < 0].tolist()
    indexmax = df.index[df.maxV > 0].tolist()
```

Comment: and where is the val column from?

Comment: i just want 1000 for negative and -1000 for positive ..the 1000 is a constant

Comment: what happens if a row has both `minV` and `maxV` defined?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we can only have one non-NaN value in a row, we can take `max` of the row, then drop NaNs with `dropna`, take sign with `np.sign` and multiply by -1000:

```
df.max(axis=1).dropna().apply(np.sign) * -1000
```

Output:

```
2008-01-04    1000.0
2008-01-07   -1000.0
2008-01-08    1000.0
```